# When is "al" not interchangeable with "a el"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

This is a clear case where "al" cannot be replaced with "a el":

> Al mirarlo, sonrió.

Are there any other cases?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To put this answer into simplest terms: No, `al` can't always replace `a el`.

Before an [*infinitive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive) of a verb, `al` means *upon* or *when*. The pattern for this usage would be as follows:

> Al <*infinitive of X*> <*result Y*> => Upon X, Y.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - Al llegar a mi casa, voy a dormir. => When I get home I'm going to sleep.
> - Al alcanzar su meta, se retiró. => Upon reaching his goal, he retired.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - In this sense `al` doesn't mean *when* in a habitual sense (e.g. *whenever*.) In those cases [`cuando`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cuando#Spanish) would be preferred.
> - The `al` clause doesn't necessarily need to be placed first in the sentence, and for stylistic purposes, it can be moved around. That said, in plain speech it will almost always be the first element in the sentence.

In this usage it *can not* be interchanged arbitarily with `a el`. Oddly enough though, very few dictionaries make mention of this.

I hope this helps! :)

**References:**

- "Google Answers: ... Al before Infinative Verb." Web. 23 Apr. 2012. <http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=483418>.

Comment: +1 It's really strange that most dictionaries (even the DRAE) omit this -very common- meaning!

Answer (score 9):

Some proper nouns that start with *el* don't contract.  Back in the day, I worked near a taquería called El Pelón, and we'd say *Vamos a El Pelón*.  But if you're in Chilangolandia and are taking a day trip to the mountains south of the city, you'd say *Vamos al Ajusco*.

The pattern for proper nouns, therefore, seems to be whether *el* is capitalized or not.  (I'm not entirely sure about this, and would appreciate confirmation or refutation.)

Comment: [Here's what DPD says](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=al). Summarizing, it's what you said: if "El" is part of the name, and therefore capitalized, it is not contracted.