# Why do you use "al" before a verb?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

I understand that al is a combination of *a + el* when used before a noun, however in what situations would you use it in front of a verb, for instance

> 'Al llegar al tercer semaforo...'

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/when-is-al-not-interchangeable-with-a-el

Comment: in spanish, "el llegar" would also kind of make sense in the sense of "el evento de la llegada". This is just not to be compared to english at all.

Comment: @Sebas I think that what you are saying is the real origin of this use of "al"!

Answer (score 4):

"Al" is mostly used when you are going to use "when" (and some other times "upon"), and it should be used before a verb.
The verb **must** be on the infinitive form (this means that it's not a personal form of the verb, and ends with "-ar", "-er" or "-ir".

Comment: Doesn't cuando mean when?

Answer (score 2):

En este caso, esta locución en un sustituto de la forma "cuando" o "en cuanto", que, de forma popular, se sustituyen en España por "a la [ocasión de] que + verbo" o "a lo que + verbo".

> *Cuando* él llegó al tercer semáforo. = *A la que* él llegó al tercer semáforo. = ***Al*** llegar él al tercer semáforo.
>
> *En cuanto* miré me di cuenta. = *A la que* miré me di cuenta. = ***Al*** mirar me di cuenta.

Debe usarse siempre con infinitivo, o bien con un verbo pronominal si la frase lo lleva, por ejemplo:

> *Cuando* me lo dijo me fui. > *A la que* me lo dijo me fui. = ***Al*** decírmelo me fui.
>
> Me gustó *en cuanto* me vi con él. = Me gustó *a la que* me vi con él. = Me gustó ***al*** verme con él.
>
> *En cuanto* lo miré me di cuenta. = *A la que* lo miré me di cuenta. = ***Al*** mirarlo me dí cuenta.

---

Uso de "al" en este contexto explicado en la RAE: http://www.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg#7

Answer (score 2):

In this context **al** is *not* a contraction of the preposition **a** and the definite article **el**, but a preposition in its own right.

When used before a verb in the infinitive (like in your example), the preposition **al** is used like the English preposition **upon** or **on** in the same context. It could aternatively be translated by a phrase such as *at the time of*.

That is to say, it is used to introduce an something which occurs simultaneously with, or immediately after, the action described by the verb.

So to take your example,
*'**Al llegar** al tercer semaforo...'*  =  *'**Upon arriving** at the third traffic light...'*
Meaning that when the subject arrives at the third traffic light, '...' will happen.

Another example might be
*'perdió el equipaje **al cambiarse** de tren'*  =  *'he lost his luggage **when he changed*** (or ***at the time of changing***) *trains'*.

Comment: For what it's worth, the *second* **al** in your example *is* a contraction of **a el**. Confusing as it may be, the two **al** s are entirely different words.

Comment: I never heard of this use of `al`. Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: I heard it a lot in Spain, but I don't know if it's used as much in South America... Can anyone comment?

Answer (score 0):

"Al llegar" is the same as "cuando llegues", which means "when you reach".

Comment: The OP is not really asking the meaning of "al llegar", but the use of "al".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest interpretation that works 99% of the time is "upon + verb"

Examples:

"Al cambiarse la ropa" = Upon changing his/her clothes...

"Al ir al baño" = Upon going to the restroom...

"Al besar a la chica" = Upon kissing the girl...

Al most always be followed by the infinitive, but it works well in a surprising number of instances and can make your sentences quite flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can think that "al llegar" is a propositional phrase in which "llegar", being an infinitive, is used as a name, because of the article "el". The preposition "a" gives this construct an adverbial taste.

But we also use other prepositions: 
- "Con el batir de palmas, el actor salió de escena"
- "Entre el ir y venir, ya no sé ni dónde estoy" 
- "Hasta el andar me quita el aliento"