# What is the difference between "al" and "a la"?

Tags: traducción, gramática, vocabulario-técnico

Consider the following sentence:

> Vamos a entender a la maestra. (We are going to understand the teacher)

I remember seeing in a similar sentence the word `al` being used instead of `a la`. So are these two ways of referencing the person interchangeable? Or are there specific contexts in which one must be used over the other?

Comment: Related to:  [When is “al” not interchangeable with “a el”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/when-is-al-not-interchangeable-with-a-el)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Vamos a entender ***a la*** maestra.

In the case of `a la maestra`, `la` is a definite article (femenino singular->feminine singular) that you put before of a noun to indicate this noun is known to the speaker.

> Vamos a entender ***al*** maestro.

`al` is the contraction of `a el` and `el` is a definite article (masculino singular->masculine singular) that you put before of a noun to indicate this noun is known to the speaker.  Unlike in English, where contractions are optional (`will not` and `won't` are grammatically interchangeable), the use of the contraction `al` is obligatory in Spanish (as is the contraction `del`, which means `de el`), except when the `el` is part of a proper noun:

- Vamos ***a El*** Salvador.  **NOT** Vamos ***al*** Salvador.

Also be sure not to confuse **el** (it) with **él** (him/he).  **a él** is never shortened:

- Vamos a verlo ***a él***.

There are five definite articles in Spanish:

- Masculine singular -> el
- Masculine plural -> los
- Feminine singular -> la
- Feminine plural -> las
- Neuter singular -> lo

[Note](http://spanish.about.com/cs/grammar/a/neuter.htm) that although in Spanish nouns are either masculine or feminine, it is possible to use the definite article `lo` to construct a neuter form. For example:

> Me gusta lo francés
>
> I like French things

---

Feel free to edit if you see any errors in my attempt in English.

Hope this helps.