# How to translate 'al' in "un delito de desobediencia al no acatar la orden"

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

## Objective

Clarify the grammar and the translation of 'al' in the sentence below. It is from RTVE article "[El TSJ catalán ve indicios de desobediencia en Artur Mas por no acatar la suspensión del 9N](http://www.rtve.es/noticias/20150108/tsj-catalan-ve-indicios-desobediencia-artur-mas-acatar-suspension-del-9n/1081205.shtml)"

> El Tribunal Superior de Justicia de Cataluña (TSJC) aprecia indicios
>   de que el presidente de la Generalitat, Artur Mas, pudo incurrir en un
>   delito de desobediencia al no acatar la orden del Tribunal
>   Constitucional (TC) que suspendía la consulta alternativa soberanista
>   del 9N.

The article is about (I think) the governor of Catalonia/Spain Artur Mas ignored a stop order and moved on to run a referendum for the independence of Catalonia, and the supreme court claims it is an offence.

### Related Topic

[When is “al” not interchangeable with “a el”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/when-is-al-not-interchangeable-with-a-el/2184#2184) says 'al + infinitive' means 'on/upon … ing' in English, indicating the timing when something happens/ed.

### Question

In the article and the context, it seems not about 'timing'. I asked a Spanish friend and she suggested it would rather be "because of":

- The TSJC assesses the evidences that the Generalist Party leader Artur Mas could commit an offence of noncompliance because of not abiding by the order from TC that suspended the inquiry of 9N

Is this understanding 'al = due to/because of' correct? 
Is there any references addressing this usage of 'al'?

I appreciate your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. “*Al* + infinive” can have a temporal or causal meaning. With negated verbs, as in this case, the causal meaning is preferred.

De la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española - Manual* de la R.A.E. (Espasa):

> **26.5.4a**     La partícula *al* en la pauta «*al* + infinitivo» (*al leer el libro*) procede de la
>   primitiva unión de preposición y artículo. No obstante, hoy parece comportarse
>   como conjunción en este contexto, ya que no introduce grupos nominales ni
>   pronombres. Las construcciones formadas con «*al* + infinitivo» pueden tener, según el
>   contexto, sentido causal o temporal. Se prefiere la interpretación causal con verbos
>   de estado (*Al ser el hermano mayor, se encargó de todo*), con predicados negados (*Al
>   no recibir noticias suyas, lo tuvo por muerto*), o cuando el infinitivo aparece en su
>   forma compuesta (*Al haberlo entendido así, ya no dijo nada*). En cambio, los adverbios focales, como *exactamente* o *justo*, favorecen el sentido temporal: *exactamente
>   al sonar el reloj*, *justo al cruzar la calle*. Tal interpretación es la única posible en las
>   variantes «*a(l) poco de* + infinitivo» y «*nada más* + infinitivo», la segunda, característica del español europeo: *Salió para el hospital {a(l) poco de ~ nada más} recibir la
>   noticia*. Lo mismo sucede con *a { las dos horas ~ los tres días ~ el rato ~ el año} de llegar
>   a la ciudad* y construcciones afines. El infinitivo admite sujeto expreso en todos estos
>   casos: *Al ser Julio el hermano mayor, ...*; *Justo al cruzar Marta la calle, ...*; *Al salir el
>   sol, ...*, de acuerdo con lo señalado en el § 26.4.2a.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the citation from RAE. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you need to take into account is that "el" plus infinitive in Spanish is often the same as a gerund used as a noun in English.  Thus,

> el no acatar

might be translated as

> not complying with

Seen in this light, "al" plus infinitive could be seen as "a" plus "el" plus infinitive, although Spanish grammar texts will generally not exlain it that way.

So

> al no acatar

Might translate

> on not complying with

Answer (score 0):

Tu traducción está bastante bien, se entiende, pero esta construcción gramatical -"al"+inf.- tiene un matiz bastante diferente al de una relación causal.

Si quisiéramos expresar 100% causalidad, en lugar de "al" usaríamos "por", que no siempre es intercambiable por "al". (En cualquier caso, siempre se cambian matices.)

La oración:

> Artur Mas pudo incurrir en un delito de desobediencia al no acatar la orden.

se entiende como:

> El hecho de que Artur Mas no haya acatado la orden hace que [Artur Mas] haya podido incurrir en un delito [de no acatar la orden].

El significado causal es una consecuencia de la situación causa-efecto que produce la construcción "al"+infinitivo, pero en el sentido estricto no es equivalente a un "por". De hecho no podemos intercambiarlo aquí:

> Artur Mas pudo incurrir en un delito de desobediencia por no acatar la orden.

Esto no queda bien, no es fiel al significado original: el no acatar la orden es el delito, no la causa del delito. Habría que cambiar la frase para que fuera fiel al sentido original, por ejemplo (¡me lo invento!):

> El TSJC penalizará a Artur Mas por no acatar la orden de suspender la consulta.

(Se sobreentiende que el no acatar la orden constituye un delito y en consecuencia debe ser penalizado.)